# Booths algorithm and right shift

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, multiplication

I know the working of booths algorithm.

Suppose we have multiplicand M = 01011

and multiplier Q = 01110

We can write Q as (2^4 - 2^1).

So multiplication reduces to 2^4(M) + 2(-M)

Now booths algorithm rules are:-

If Q = 0 and Q(-1)=0 then do arithmetic right shift.

If Q = 1 and Q(-1)=0 then do A-M and arithmetic right shift.

If Q = 0 and Q(-1)=1 then do A+M and arithmetic right shift.

If Q = 1 and Q(-1)=1 then do arithmetic right shift.

Here A is initialized to 00000 and Q(-1) is initialized to 0.

If we see the algorithm then in every step we do right shifting. But as per the calculation shown above which is 2^4(M) + 2(-M) we multiply by 16 and 2 which requires left shift.

So how is booths algorithm working with right shift ? I am not able to get the intuition behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This variant of Booth's algorithm produces the top W bits of the multiplication M*Q, where both M and Q have W bits.

The result will be placed on Accumulator A, having also W bits. It's possible to recover the low bits as well -- especially in assembler, using `SHR acc, 1; RCR low, 1` sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [document](http://users.utcluj.ro/~baruch/book_ssce/SSCE-Shift-Mult.pdf), it clearly states shift - and - add multiplication algorithm. The unoptimised algorithm uses left shift and optimised algorithm uses right shift to reduce space usage of registers. Now this acts as base for booth's algorithm.